# Как разрешаются ситуации злонамеренного бронирования услуг?

Tags: безопасность, архитектура, микросервисы, it-бизнес

**Ситуация:**

1. Есть объект, которому может быть присвоен VIP-статус.
2. Количество VIP-мест ограничено.
3. **Оплата** VIP-мест планируется **напрямую**, без использования средств,
   занесенных заранее на счет покупателя.
4. Оплата VIP-места возможна без регистрации в системе.

***Сценарий:***

1. При оформлении заказа на покупку VIP-места это VIP-место резервируется на определенное время.
2. В течение данного времени покупателю необходимо оплатить оформленный
   заказ.
3. Если заказ не был оплачен, то по истечении заданного времени:

   - заказ будет отменен;
   - зарезервированное VIP-место будет свободно для покупки.

**Потенциальная угроза:**

Группа злоумышленников может просто периодически бронировать VIP-места без оплаты заказа.

**Вопрос:**
Как в таких случаях разрешаются ситуации злонамеренного бронирования услуг?

Comment: при бронировании обычно спрашивают контакты либо счет карты оплаты, а непросто бронь. Вам нужно спрашивать дополнительно данные что занести в чёрный список в случае угроз

Comment: Заказ на покупку VIP-места можно будет сделать анонимно. Бронирование VIP-места осуществляется самой системой после оформления заказа на определенное время.

Answer (score 4):

При бронировании обычно спрашивают контакты либо счет карты оплаты, а не просто бронь. Вам нужно спрашивать дополнительно данные, чтобы занести в чёрный список в случае угроз.

Варианты:

1. Спросить номер кредитной карты
2. Паспортные данные
3. Код верификации на телефон
4. Капчи и всякое такое, запоминаем IP адрес. Заставляем авторизоваться через доверенные системы.
5. Системы поощрения, если человек ответственный то + иначе -
6. Владелец золотой/платиновой ... карты Master Card
7. Не предлагать бронирование для новых клиентов без истории успешных покупок на определённую сумму или бронь только для VIP клиентов которые уже занесены в базу лояльных клиентов

.....

Одним словом, делают систему бронирования не удобной для злоумышленника и максимально удобной для порядочных клиентов.

И в любой системе бронирования убытки неизбежны. Остаётся лишь минимизировать их. Чем проще система, тем больше потенциальных покупателей, но и злоумышленников тоже много, соответственно.

Comment: 1) не имеет права 2) скорее всего не имеет права 3) смс стоит денег и ничего не даст 4) ну вот это, имхо, более-менее 5) странно 6) не имеет права

Comment: @nörbörnën на счет прав это не ко мне. В моей системе если все это не сделать то расчетный счет не открыть. А попасть в чёрный список можно легко в нем даже есть главы государств.

Comment: на счет смс - денег стоит да, но доверие надо строить, а не ломать. Издержки они везде и этого не избежать полностью

Comment: 7. Перефразировал

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы.
Под бронирование подразумевалось бронирование именно VIP-места перед оплатой.
Также внес корректировку в разделе "Ситуация" - оплата возможна без регистрации.

Comment: на счет оплаты "Оплата VIP-места возможна без регистрации в системе" но авторизоваться через 3 и системы можно требовать

Comment: То есть Вы предлагаете при оформлении заказа отправлять покупателю sms для авторизации на оформление и только потом допускать его к оплате? Т. е. своеобразная sms-капча?)

Comment: @Eladei скорее, совершать "бронирование" только после ввода кода из sms. на этапе отсылки sms можно отсеивать недобросовестных клиентов по некоему справочнику телефонных номеров

Comment: @nörbörnën, идея интересная. Только скажите, пожалуйста, почему ранее вы про sms-верификацию сказали, что "... и ничего не даст"? Или я тогда Вас не правильно понял?

Comment: @Eladei можно использовать не только свой телефонный номер